# Results on Hall $\pi$-subgroups - proof verification

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, proof-verification

I would appreciate verification of the following proofs.  The problems are all closely related and the proofs are similar, so I think it's only appropriate to post them together (also, they are part of the same multi-part problem).

Let $\pi$ be a set of prime numbers, and let $G$ be a finite group.  A subgroup $H \le G$ is called a $\pi$-subgroup if every prime dividing its order lies in $\pi$.  If in addition, no prime dividing its index lies in $\pi$, we say that $H$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup.  Note that if $H$ and $K$ are Hall $\pi$-subgroups, then $|H|=|K|$.

a) Show that G contains a unique largest normal $\pi$-subgroup.

Let $H$ and $K$ be largest-order normal $\pi$-subgroups of $G$.  If $H$ and $K$ are trivial, the result follows trivially.  Since $H,K \triangleleft G$, $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$.  In particular it is a normal $\pi$-subgroup of $G$.  Since $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$, we have that $|H| \le |HK| \le |H||K|$.  But if $|KH| > |H|$, this contradicts the fact that $H$ and $K$ are largest normal $\pi$-subgroups of $G$.  It follows that $H=K$ and the largest normal $\pi$-subgroup of $G$ is unique.

b) If $H \le G$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup, show that $H$ contains every normal $\pi$-subgroup of $G$.

Let $H \le G$ be a Hall $\pi$-subgroup and let $K$ be a normal $\pi$-subgroup.  We can assume that $|K| \le |H|$, since otherwise $K$ would not be a $\pi$-subgroup because $\gcd(|H|,|G:H|)=1$.  Since $K$ is normal, $HK$ is also a $\pi$-subgroup of $G$.  Then we have $|G:H|=|G:HK||HK:H|$.  Since $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$, we have $|HK:H|=\frac{|K|}{|H \cap K|}$, which is only divisible by primes in $\pi$, since $K$ and $H \cap K$ are $\pi$-subgroups.  But $|G:H|$ is coprime to every member of $\pi$, which forces $|HK:H|=1$.  Therefore $H=HK$ and so $K \le H$.

c) Suppose that $G$ has a normal Hall $\pi$-subgroup $M$.  Show that $M$ contains every $\pi$-subgroup of $G$.  Conclude that $M$ is the unique Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $G$.

Let $M$ be a normal Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $G$ and let $K$ be a $\pi$-subgroup of $G$.  We can assume $|K| \le |M|$ since $M$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup and otherwise $K$ would fail to be a $\pi$-subgroup.  Since $M$ is normal, $MK$ is a $\pi$-subgroup of $G$.  Consider that $|G:M|=|G:MK||MK:M|$.  Since $MK$ and $M$ are $\pi$-subgroups but $\gcd(|M|,|G:M|)=1$, we must have $|MK:M|=1$ and $K \le M$.

I appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: @Deiborlang: Thanks, I appreciate it.